# Android Intent with NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-intent

There are many many questions about starting new `Intent` from another `Intent` but i'm unable to find solutions of mine. In my main `Activity` i started an `Activity` this way

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DownloadManagerSettings.class);
intent.putExtra("DM_SETTINGS_ACTIVITY", "MainActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

and trying to get extra `String` value this way

```
public class DownloadManagerSettings extends Activity {

private Button dmOk;
private Bundle extra;
private String className;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dm_settings);
    extra = getIntent().getExtras();

    dmOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dm_settings_ok);

    final Bundle strExtra = extra;

    dmOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            className = strExtra.getString("DM_SETTINGS_ACTIVITY");
            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(DownloadManagerSettings.this, Class.forName(className));
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

But in my LogCat shows following error

```
08-28 14:19:33.777: E/AndroidRuntime(17837): java.lang.NullPointerException08-28 14:19:33.777: E/AndroidRuntime(17837):     at com.downloadmanager.settings.DownloadManagerSettings$1.onClick(DownloadManagerSettings.java:101)
```

Here 101 Line is

```
className = strExtra.getString("DM_SETTINGS_ACTIVITY");
```

**UPDATE**

new error

```
08-28 14:55:11.237: E/AndroidRuntime(24623): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 08-28 14:55:11.237: E/AndroidRuntime(24623):     at com.downloadmanager.settings.DownloadManagerSettings.onCreate(DownloadManagerSettings.java:66)
```

66 Line is

```
className = strExtra.getString("DM_SETTINGS_ACTIVITY");
```

**NEW UPDATE1**

Now

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DownloadManagerSettings.class);
intent.putExtra(getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+".DM_SETTINGS_ACTIVITY", "MainActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

Another Activity

```
className = getIntent().getStringExtra(getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+".DM_SETTINGS_ACTIVITY");
final String newClass = className;
Log.d("DM_AAAAAAAA", className);
dmOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

Find in LogCat

```
08-28 15:09:14.670: E/AndroidRuntime(27291): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.addon.downloadmanager/com.downloadmanager.settings.DownloadManagerSettings}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to replace this code : className = getIntent().getStringExtra("DM_SETTINGS_ACTIVITY");

Comment: Why exactly are you passing the class name? Assuming you don't call `finish()` in your `MainActivity` all you have to do is call `finish()` in the `onClick(...)` method of your `DowloadManagerSettings` `Activity` in order to return to `MainActivity` - there is no need to start a new instance.

Comment: @Squonk- after clicking ok button MainActivity will be updated. So `finish()` will not update MainActivity

Comment: @user3384985 : "MainActivity will be updated"...Um, how exactly do you propose to do that?

Comment: actually i've a `MenuItem` in MainActivity. when i'll click to the `MenuItem` then DownloadManagerSettings Activity will be started and after clicking ok `Button` then data will be saved in `SQlite` and MainActivity will start with update settings

Comment: @user3384985 : So just use `onResume()` in your `MainActivity` to reload the data from your database. When you start your `DownloadManagerSettings` `Activity` the `onPause()` method of `MainActivity` will be called and if you then call `finish()` in `DownloadManagerSettings` `onClick` it will return to `MainActivity` where `onResume()` will be called.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
    public class DownloadManagerSettings extends Activity {

    private Button dmOk;
    private Bundle extra;
    private String className;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dm_settings);
        extra = getIntent().getExtras();

        dmOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dm_settings_ok);

        final Bundle strExtra = extra;
        className = strExtra.getString("DM_SETTINGS_ACTIVITY");

        dmOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method 
                try {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(DownloadManagerSettings.this, Class.forName(className));
                    startActivity(intent);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Get the String data in `onCreate` first and then use it in `onClick`.

**Update** :
seems you'll have to add your package name as the prefix, see [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.CharSequence)). After that, use [`getStringExtra`/`getCharSequenceExtra`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringExtra(java.lang.String)) to get the string data.(note we don't use Bundle any more). This should work.

**update 1**:

The following code work on my device.

```
    Intent newIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
    newIntent.setClass(this, SecondActivity.class);
    newIntent.putExtra(getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+".abc", "test");
    startActivity(newIntent);
```

and in the other activity:

```
String data = getIntent().getStringExtra(getIntent().getAction()+".abc");
```

Comment: **"note we don't use Bundle any more"** : Huh? It might not be necessary to get the `Bundle` used to carry `Intent` extras but there's nothing wrong with doing so. Methods such as `getStringExtra(...)` are simply convenience methods.

Comment: @Squonk, you're right, I just want to point out the difference.

Comment: @user3384985, it's because `className` has a NULL value. `Log.d` internally use `print*`.

Comment: @user3384985, I have tried your code in last update on my device, it works well

Comment: error because two Activities within different package

Comment: @user3384985, pass the first package name as the Action and call `getAction` in the second activity. Then you can use it to get the string

Comment: sorry for your time. still getting `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 2):

From the [javadoc of Intent.putExtra(String,String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) :

> The name must include a package prefix, for example the app com.android.contacts would use names like "com.android.contacts.ShowAll".

So try this :

```
intent.putExtra(getPackageManager().getPackageName()+".DM_SETTINGS_ACTIVITY", "MainActivity");
```

and later:

```
className = strExtra.getString(getPackageManager().getPackageName()+".DM_SETTINGS_ACTIVITY");
```

Comment: **"The name must include a package prefix"** : This isn't actually true. I never use package prefixes and don't have any problems.

Comment: @Squonck hum... let's say that you never use it and your code works. BUT it is true that it is in the javadoc AND it is true that it solves the OP error (at least the first one)

Comment: I'm not saying that it isn't in the javadoc but there again there are a lot of parts of the Android documentation that are incorrect, incomplete or ambiguous. It *IS* (without doubt) possible to use `intent.putExtra("my_key", "my_value")` without using a package prefix for the 'key' - try it yourself and prove me wrong. As for your suggestion solving the OP's problem, I can't see any evidence of that in any of the OP's updates to their question. There is something fundamentally wrong with their code and I suspect it's somewhere in code they haven't provided.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getStringExtra()` instead of `getExtra()`

or you can also do in from other side during intenet creation

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DownloadManagerSettings.class);
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString("DM_SETTINGS_ACTIVITY", "MainActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DownloadManagerSettings.class);
intent.putExtra("DM_SETTINGS_ACTIVITY", "MainActivity");
startActivity(intent);

className =  className = getIntent().getStringExtra("DM_SETTINGS_ACTIVITY");
```

**OR**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DownloadManagerSettings.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("DM_SETTINGS_ACTIVITY", "MainActivity");
startActivity(intent);


className =  className = getIntent().getBundleExtra().getString("DM_SETTINGS_ACTIVITY");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is here,

```
intent.putExtra(getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+".DM_SETTINGS_ACTIVITY", "MainActivity");
```

Just **replace** this line with

```
intent.putExtra("MainActivity",getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+".DM_SETTINGS_ACTIVITY");
```

Check this code :

```
 1. **MainActivity.java**

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity2.class);

         intent.putExtra("MY TEXT", getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+".TestActivity");
         startActivity(intent);


 2. **MainActivity2.java**




 Intent i = getIntent();
    final String className = i.getStringExtra("MY TEXT");
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity2.this,Class.forName(className));
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
```

This is worked on my device.